# Using setValue() in a loop returns an "Uncaught error"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to update my a sheet upon pressing submit on a form. Upon submitting, the page does not iterate the remaining commands and would show an error on the console as "Uncaught  at updateMan (Server:67) (Easy Roster) 3bf79b2b-341b-490f-87a8-b293d7ded973". But when I checked my sheet, the values were definitely changed to the new ones I set for each cell. Where does the error come from and how do I fix this?

```js
//server side
function updateMan(data)
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Easy Roster");
  var length = data.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    var max = length - 1;
    var row = data[i] + 1;
    var newMan = data[max];
    sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(newMan);
  }

  return length;
}
```

```
//front-end
  function updateData(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();

    var checkedRows = [];

    var nRows = document.getElementById("tableBody").childNodes.length;


    for (var i = 1; i < nRows; i++)
    {
      var checkbox = document.getElementById(i);

      if (checkbox.checked)
      {
        var row = document.getElementById("row" + i).childNodes;
        row[5].text == e.target["newManField"].value; 
        checkedRows.push(i);
      }
    }

    checkedRows.push(e.target["newManField"].value);

    console.log(checkedRows); 

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateAlert)
      .updateMan(checkedRows);
  }

  function updateAlert(data)
  {
    console.log(data);
    alert("Employee details have been updated.");
    window.open("link_to_page", '_top');  
  }
```

Comment: Catch it with `withFailureHandler()`?

Comment: The solution you offered was adequate to run it. Thanks for your help :)
But with regards to best practices and other stuff to consider in coding, how do I "properly" fix this?

Comment: What did you catch in the failure handler? What does it say?

Comment: It returned the same error I wrote. "Uncaught at updateMan (Server:67) (Easy Roster) 3bf79b2b-341b-490f-87a8-b293d7ded973"

Comment: If the below answer did not work, kindly update your question with the latest code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that your last call to `sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue(newMan)` is using the **string** from `data[max]` with "1" concatenated to it.  Remove that last element from the array before looping.

Here is a modified version of `updateMan` that should be functionally equivalent, but without the error.

```js
/**
 * @param {mixed[]} data - list of row numbers, zero-indexed,
 *   final array element is a string
 */
function updateMan(data) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Easy Roster");
  var length = data.length;  
  var newMan = data.pop(); // removes "newMan" from array

  data.forEach(function (row) { 
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 5).setValue(newMan);
  });

  return length; // length prior to the pop - check if that's what you want
}
```

In your client-side code, what you posted contains what appears to be a typo (although it has nothing to do with the error from the server):

```js
row[5].text == e.target["newManField"].value; // comparison that does nothing
```

which I assume you meant to be

```js
row[5].textContent = e.target["newManField"].value; // assign some text content
```

Comment: There were no more errors after trying this solution. Thank you for your help and for explaining things clearly :)